# Python match syntax for evaluating typing objects

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-typing

I'm trying to use a `match` block to evaluate the types being returned from `typing.get_type_hints`. I want to use the type hinting to determine what code path to take in order to instantiate the appropriate value.

```
class Foo:
  x: int = 0
  y: float = 0.0
  z: str = ''

name = 'x'  # comes from an external source
value = '42'
type_hints = get_type_hints(Foo)
foo = Foo()

match type_hints[name]:
  case int:
    foo[name] = int(value)
  case float:
    foo[name] = int(value)
  case str:
    foo[name] = value
  # TODO: other complex type parsing (e.g., Enums)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
C:\dev\bdk-git\bdk\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/dev/bdk-git/bdk/material/reader.py
  File "C:\dev\bdk-git\bdk\material\reader.py", line 22
    case int:
         ^^^
SyntaxError: name capture 'int' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

What is the correct syntax to accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match/case` is used for pattern matching, not for simple equality testing. A simple name like `int` is a pattern that matches anything, and sets `int` to the value.

You should use ordinary `if` conditions.

```
h = type_hints[name]
if h == int:
    foo[name] = int(value)
elif h == float:
    foo[name] = float(value)
elif h == str:
    foo[name] = value
else:
    print(f"Unknown type {h}")
```

Comment: Thanks!  How does that differ from `match n: 5: return 'five'`?  `h` is a subject, `int` may be its value, right?

Comment: Ah - I see: https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#literal-patterns are limited to numbers, strings and booleans.  No types are allowed.  That's arbitrary.

Comment: Types aren't literals, they're variables whose values are type objects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the type hints here, but to structurally match based on class you need to provide a variable to which the value will be assigned, e.g.

```py
foo = some_func()

match foo:
    case int(value):
        print(f"{value} is an integer")
    case float(value):
        print(f"{value} is a float")
```

This checks whether `foo`'s type is *already* an `int` or a `float` (or a subtype thereof) and binds it to `value`, so no need to do `int(value)` inside the match body.